# Why can't this event call its parent event?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, events, inheritance

It's me... Back again... with another Unreal problem...

---

I have an `Event` in my `Parent Class` called `Overridable :: PreDialogueScreenEnter`

[image]

I have overridden the same Event in a Child Class:

[image]

Yet when I attempt to call the parent event from the child class, the option is greyed out.

[image]

---

**Tl;Dr:**

Why call parent event not work >:|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question within minutes of asking the damn thing.

---

**How I created this problem**

When overriding parent events in Unreal, you must right click and use the context menu to add the event you want to override.

Instead, I created a custom event and named it identically to the parent event.

This provides the *same functionality*, where the overridden event is the only one called.

**However**, it does not register within the editor as an overridden event, thus the option I required never showed up.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks for explaining the cause for others to learn from. 

Comment: Figured I'm not the only person who's ever gonna come across this problem